# How do I store the result of a function in the same object?

Tags: javascript

**Question:**  I created an object that contained 2 named values.  One is a function and the other is the value produced by the function.  My problem is that I can't figure out the syntax for the second named value.  How do I reference it?  I've looked everywhere but I can't find a similar example object that I can learn from. Thanks so much!

```
var answer = {
    addNumbers: function(a, b, c) {
        return a + b + c;
    },
    result: answer.addNumbers;  //I'm not sure what the syntax is for this line.
};
```

Comment: You would use `result: answer.addNumbers(your, numbers, here)` because `result: answer.addNumbers` just stores the function in the result as well

Comment: What numbers do you wand to add? Or do you want to store the result always the function was executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get what you want to do, but if you want to store the result everytime the function gets executed, you might want to do something like this:

```
var answer = {
    addNumbers: function(a, b, c) {
        this.result = a + b + c;
        return this.result;
    },

    result:0
};
```

I think I'll explain the JSON a little bit:

In general, you just list a number of properties. Here, we specify `addNumbers` and `result` and assign values to them.

The value for `addNumbers` is a `Function`-object (thus callable), the value for `result` is a `Number`-object (`0` in this case).

You now can execute `addNumbers` by calling it like `answer.addNumbers(1,2,3)`. When this happens, everything between `{` and `}` of the function body gets executed, including the new assignment of `this.result`.

There's more stuff to this topic, especially how `this` is resolved in several cases, but that would exceed the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thanks that absolutely works!  Why did you assign a value of 0 to result with `result:0`?  That works, I'm just not sure why.

Comment: I assigned 0 as the initial value. It gets overwritten everytime the function is executed, but it should have a value in the first place.

Comment: @DR01D, you could alternatively not even specify a result property inital value. If you try to access it, it will return `undefined`. Setting it from `addNumbers` will still work fine. Yet anothe option: you could set it to `null` initially.

Comment: I'm learning objects so this was a thought experiment.  But now I see that my problem wasn't so much in result as much as the way I built addNumbers.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Would the following be acceptable to you?

```
var addNumbers = function(a, b, c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
var answer = {
    addNumbers: addNumbers,
    result: addNumbers(...)
};
```

Alternatively:

```
var answer = {
    addNumbers: function(a, b, c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }
};
answer.result = answer.addNumbers(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

The last result of the function can also be stored in the function object:

```js
function addNumbers(a, b, c) {
    addNumbers.result = a + b + c
    return addNumbers.result
}

addNumbers(1,2,3)

console.log(addNumbers.result)
```

Otherwise, it's possible by executing a function that accepts another function and returns the object:

```js
var result = (function(f, a, b, c) { 
  return {
    addNumbers: f,
    result: f(a, b, c)
  }
})(function(a, b, c) { return a + b + c }, 1, 2, 3)

console.log(result)
```